# Using clients' Apple account on Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios

So I have been building an app for a client with my Apple Developer Membership and bundle ID. Now the client registered his own individual account on the Apple Developer portal. What should I do to publish the app to the App Store: change the app bundle ID or the team on Xcode?

Comment: Bundle id format is like : com.companyname.appname so better to change it too with your client company name and configure client apple account also by making auto configure of certificate in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a nice to mention the client company in the bundle id so that whenever they will transfer to other developer , it will be uniquely and systematically maintained these things , here is the step :

1. Open Xcode Preference -> add apple account ( client account )
2. Create bundle id with client company name and certificate and
   provisioning profile also

Here is the screenshot : [image]

**Automatically manage signing** helps you to do things easily and when you want to push it , create your distribution certi and provisioning also if you want .

Feel free to comment.